# Restoring Gitlab instance with data from AWS EBS Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, snapshot, amazon-ebs

I have hosted a gitlab instance over AWS ec2 instance and attached it with some EBS volume. Howeevr, due to some OS crash my instance became unreachable. Now I have created the snapshot of existing EBS volume and attached it to another ec2 instance named ec-2. I have mounted the storage at a location data in the root directory. Is it possible that I can retrieve the already existing GItlab instance with data on the new ec2 named ec-2 . I have checked the backup directory of the gitlab at location /var/opt/gitlab/backups
But it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a backup command needs to be explicitly run to populate the backups directory. So if that was not setup to be run it's not a surprise this directory is empty.

You should have access to some interesting data however, for example configuration at least.

You may need to dig into some docs but some places to check:

- /etc/gitlab
- /var/log/gitlab (not likely too interesting)
- /var/opt/gitlab (could have good stuff)

Depends on your configuration of course but good luck.